# Roulette Ball Tracking with Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, tracking

There is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsxkg.jpg) from roulette spin [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/esecgfc6qfjfkfz/frame.avi?dl=0), and I have a code to track the ball position on the image

[image]

```
(*Mask is a visible ball track on the rim*)
```

[image]

```
Module[{ball,c},

ball=FillingTransform@DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[ImageSubtract[img,Mask],.42],100];

c = Flatten[ComponentMeasurements[ball,{"Centroid","BoundingDiskRadius"}][[All,2]],1];

Show[img, Graphics[{Thickness[.01], Magenta, Circle @@ c}]]]
```

it works  :)

[image]

But I want to track the ball position in the video  instead of image.

there is a list of images

```
frames = Import["C:\\Users\\vito\\Desktop\\frame.avi", {"ImageList"}];
```

how can I change my code to get a desired result?

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas

Comment: Why not just run your code on each frame of the video?

Comment: Perhaps [`ImageFeatureTrack`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFeatureTrack.html) could help.